# Storing large maps in memory

Tags: java, performance, graph, guava

**First the context of the problem:** I have a a very large graph that cost about 4GB to store. About 3M nodes and 34M edges. My program takes this large graph and recursively builds smaller graphs from it. At each level of the recursion I have two graphs - the original graph and the graph created from the original. The recursion continues until the graph is reduced to very small graph say about 10 nodes.

Since I need these graphs for the entire execution of the program, Memory efficiency is critical for my application.

**Now here's the problem I'm currently having:**
This is the algorithm for creating a smaller graph from the larger one:

```
public static Graph buildByTriples(Graph g, ArrayList<Integer> seeds) {
    ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList(g.getEdgeCount());
    for (int i = 0; i < g.size(); i++) {
        for (Edge e : g.adj(i)) {
            int v = e.getEndpoint(i);
            if (i < v) {
                edges.add(e);
            }
        }
    }

    Table<Integer, Integer, Double> coarseEgdes = HashBasedTable.create(seeds.size(),seeds.size());
    //compute coarse weights
    edges.stream().forEach((e) -> {
        int v = e.getV();
        int u = e.getU();
        if (g.isC(u) && g.isC(v)) {
            addToTable(coarseEgdes, u, v, e.getWeight());
        }else if(!g.isC(u) && g.isC(v)){ //F-C
            for(Edge cEdge: g.cAdj(u)){//get coarse neighbors of the fine edges
                int nb = cEdge.getEndpoint(u);
                if(nb != v){
                    addToTable(coarseEgdes, v, nb, cEdge.getPij() * e.getWeight());

                }
            }
        }else if(g.isC(u) && !g.isC(v)){//C-F
            for(Edge cEdge: g.cAdj(v)){//get coarse neighbors of the fine edges
                int nb = cEdge.getEndpoint(v);
                if(nb != u){
                    addToTable(coarseEgdes, u, nb, cEdge.getPij() * e.getWeight());
                }
            }
        }else{//F-F
            for(Edge cEdgeU: g.cAdj(u)){//get coarse neighbors of the fine edges
                int uNb = cEdgeU.getEndpoint(u);
                for(Edge cEdgeV: g.cAdj(v)){
                    int vNb = cEdgeV.getEndpoint(v);
                    if(uNb != vNb){
                        addToTable(coarseEgdes, uNb, vNb, cEdgeU.getPij() * e.getWeight() * cEdgeV.getPij());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return createGraph(g, coarseEgdes); //use the edges to build new graph. Basically loops through coarseEdges and add edge and weight to the new graph.
}

private static void addToTable(Table<Integer, Integer,Double> tbl, int r, int c, double val){
    int mn = Math.min(r, c);//the smaller of the two nodeIds
    int mx = Math.min(r, c);//the largest of the two nodeId
    if(tbl.contains(mn, mx)){
        tbl.put(mn, mx, tbl.get(mn, mx) + val);
    }else{
        tbl.put(mn, mx,val);
    }
}
```

Now when I do this, I quickly run out of memory. I profiled the application with [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/), and memory usage is over the roof (>6GB before it runs out) and consequently CPU usage too. `coarseEdges` can get really large. Is there a better in-memory Map implementation out there that scales with large datasets? Or is there a better way to do this without storing `coarseEdges`?

PS: Note that my graph cannot retrieve an edge(u,v) in constant time. It's basically a list of list and this serves performance of other critical part of my application better.

```
**Also See my graph implementation code below: **
public class Graph{
    private final int SIZE;
    private final EdgeList[] nodes;
    private final float[] volumes;
    private final double[] weightedSum;
    private final double[] weightedCoarseSum;
    private final int[] nodeDegrees;
    private final int[] c_nodeDegrees;
    private int edge_count=0;
    private final boolean[] coarse;
    private final EdgeList[] coarse_neighbors;
    public Graph(int SIZE){
        this.SIZE =SIZE;
        nodes = new EdgeList[SIZE];
        coarse_neighbors = new EdgeList[SIZE];

        volumes = new float[SIZE];
        coarse = new boolean[SIZE];

        //initialize data
        weightedSum = new double[SIZE];
        weightedCoarseSum = new double[SIZE];
        nodeDegrees= new int[SIZE];
        c_nodeDegrees = new int[SIZE];

        for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
            nodes[i]=new EdgeList();
            coarse_neighbors[i] = new EdgeList();
            volumes[i]=1;
        }
    }

    public void addEdge(int u, int v, double w){
        //graph is undirected
        //In order to traverse edges in order such that u < v. We store edge u,v such that u<v
        Edge e=null;
        if(u<v){
            e = new Edge(u,v,w);
        }else if(u>v){
            e = new Edge(v,u,w);
        }else{
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Self loops not allowed in graph"); //TODO: Need a graph validation routine
        }

        nodes[u].add(e);
        nodes[v].add(e);

        //update the weighted sum of each edge
        weightedSum[u] += w;
        weightedSum[v] += w;

        //update the degree of each edge
        ++nodeDegrees[u];
        ++nodeDegrees[v];

        ++edge_count;
    }

    public int size(){
        return SIZE;
    }

    public EdgeList adj(int v){
        return nodes[v];
    }

    public EdgeList cAdj(int v){
        return coarse_neighbors[v];
    }

    public void sortAdj(int u, Comparator<Edge> c){
        nodes[u].sort(c);
    }

    public void sortCoarseAdj(int u, Comparator<Edge> c){
        coarse_neighbors[u].sort(c);
    }

    public void setCoarse(int node, boolean c){
        coarse[node] = c;
        if(c){
            //update the neighborHood of node
            for(Edge e: adj(node)){
                int v = e.getEndpoint(node);
                coarse_neighbors[v].add(e);
                weightedCoarseSum[v] += e.getWeight();
                ++c_nodeDegrees[v];
            }
        }
    }

    public int getEdgeCount(){
        return edge_count;
    }

    public boolean isC(int id){
        return coarse[id];
    }

    public double weightedDegree(int node){
        return weightedSum[node];
    }

    public double weightedCoarseDegree(int node){
        return weightedCoarseSum[node];
    }

    public int degree(int u){
        return nodeDegrees[u];
    }

    public int cDegree(int u){
        return c_nodeDegrees[u];
    }

    public Edge getCNeighborAt(int u,int idx){
        return coarse_neighbors[u].getAt(idx);
    }

    public float volume(int u){
        return volumes[u];
    }

    public void setVolume(int node, float v){
        volumes[node] = v;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Graph[nodes:"+SIZE+",edges:"+edge_count+"]";
    }

}


//Edges are first class objects.
public class Edge {
    private boolean deleted=false;
    private int u;
    private int v;
    private double weight;
    private double pij;
    private double algebraicDist = (1/Constants.EPSILON);

    public Edge(int u, int v, double weight) {
        this.u = u;
        this.v = v;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Edge() {
    }

    public int getU() {
        return u;
    }

    public void setU(int u) {
        this.u = u;
    }

    public int getV() {
        return v;
    }

    public void setV(int v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public int getEndpoint(int from){
        if(from == v){
            return u;
        }

        return v;
    }

    public double getPij() {
        return pij;
    }

    public void setPij(double pij) {
        this.pij = pij;
    }

    public double getAlgebraicDist() {
        return algebraicDist;
    }

    public void setAlgebraicDist(double algebraicDist) {
        this.algebraicDist = algebraicDist;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Edge[u:"+u+", v:"+v+"]";
    }
}


// The Edge iterable
public class EdgeList implements Iterable<Edge>{
    private final ArrayList<Edge> data= new ArrayList();

    public void add(Edge e){
        data.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Edge> iterator() {
        Iterator<Edge> it = new IteratorImpl();
        return it;
    }

    private class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Edge> {

        public IteratorImpl() {
        }
        private int currentIndex = 0;
        private final int N = data.size();
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {

            //skip deleted
            while(currentIndex < N && data.get(currentIndex).isDeleted()){
                currentIndex++;
            }

            return currentIndex < N;
        }

        @Override
        public Edge next() {
            return data.get(currentIndex++);
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    public Edge getAt(int idx){
        return data.get(idx);
    }

    public void sort(Comparator<Edge> c){
        data.sort(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `Graph` implementation are you using? A `Graph` interface is available in `com.google.guava:guava:20.0-SNAPSHOT` but its API does not have these methods. I'm finding it a bit difficult to follow your algorithm without understanding what different methods do, etc.

Comment: The graph is my implementation. I have included the graph implementation for your reference.

Comment: This question is fine here, but would also be a good fit for [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java), where you could get some useful general advice. A side note: Your `next` and `hasNext" are broken (although they work in the common scenario).

Comment: I found a way to use an arraylist that was comparably fast and more memory efficient. I'll post it to CR since I could still use the help.

Answer (score 4):

Few stabs in the blind here - you will need to implement them to see how much it helps.

1) You might consider using composite key (int,int) with hashmap, rather than guava table. It will be certainly more efficient for just edge weights. If you need to query edges outgoing from certain vertex, then it is less obvious, but you need to see cpu versus memory tradeoff.

2) If you use plain hashmap, you can consider using one of off-heap implementations. Take a look at https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map for example, it might

3) If you stay in memory and want to squeeze some extra space, you can do some dirty tricks with primitive maps. Use long->double map, for example http://labs.carrotsearch.com/download/hppc/0.4.1/api/com/carrotsearch/hppc/LongDoubleMap.html or http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TLongDoubleHashMap.html, encode your 2xint vertex pair into long and see how much it helps. If you are using 64 bit, Integer can take 16 bytes (assuming compressed oops), Double 24 bytes - which gives 32+24=56 bytes per entry, as compared to 8+8 with primitive map

Comment: Renumbering the nodes and switching to `ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Double>>` made a difference. I did not try any of the other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest giving Guava's [ValueGraph](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/graph/ValueGraph.html) a look for cases like these.

It's possible that you might be able to make your data structures for the recursive graphs more efficient; how many recursive steps are there for your data set, and how are the sizes of the graphs changing?

Comment: I walked away from the project for a while but I'll plan to revisit later today and would into ValueGraph. The recursive level varies with the size and structure of the graph and the minimum number of nodes necessary to terminate the recursion.  It's based on this paper: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~achi/LOP155.pdf